# Why is my reducer behaving differently between the first filter and subsequent filters applied in dc.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, dc.js, crossfilter

I'm working on [a data visualization](https://ayyrickay.github.io/circulating-magazines/) that has an odd little bug:

[image: gif of the data visualization]

It's a little tricky to see, but essentially, when I click on a point in the line chart, that point corresponds to a specific issue of a magazine. The choropleth updates to reflect geodata for that issue, but, critically, the geodata is for *a sampled period that corresponds to the issue.* Essentially, the choropleth will look the same for any issue between January-June or July-December of a given year.

As you can see, I have a key called Sampled Issue Date (for Geodata), and the value should be the date of the issue for which the geodata is based on (basically, they would get geographical distribution for one specific issue and call it representative of ALL data in a six month period.) Yet, when I initially click on an issue, I'm always getting the last sampled date in my data. All of the geodata is correct, and, annoyingly, all subsequent clicks display the correct information. So it's only that first click (after refreshing the page OR clearing an issue) that I have a problem.

Honestly, my code is a nightmare right now because I'm focused on debugging, but you can [see my reducer for the remove function on GitHub](https://github.com/ayyrickay/circulating-magazines/blob/caefe8143c8f6ed1ec3947696cdc3a63edaf593c/assets/js/index.js#L148) which is also copy/pasted below:

```
  // Reducer function for raw geodata
  function geoReducerAdd(p, v) {
    // console.log(p.sampled_issue_date, v.sampled_issue_date, state.periodEnding, state.periodStart)
    ++p.count
    p.sampled_mail_subscriptions += v.sampled_mail_subscriptions
    p.sampled_single_copy_sales += v.sampled_single_copy_sales
    p.sampled_total_sales += v.sampled_total_sales
    p.state_population = v.state_population // only valid for population viz
    p.sampled_issue_date = v.sampled_issue_date
    return p
  }

  function geoReducerRemove(p, v) {
    const currDate = new Date(v.sampled_issue_date)
    // if(currDate.getFullYear() === 1921) {
    //   console.log(currDate)
    // }
    currDate <= state.periodEnding && currDate >= state.periodStart ? console.log(v.sampled_issue_date, p.sampled_issue_date) : null
    const dateToRender = currDate <= state.periodEnding && currDate >= state.periodStart ? v.sampled_issue_date : p.sampled_issue_date
    --p.count
    p.sampled_mail_subscriptions -= v.sampled_mail_subscriptions
    p.sampled_single_copy_sales -= v.sampled_single_copy_sales
    p.sampled_total_sales -= v.sampled_total_sales
    p.state_population = v.state_population // only valid for population viz
    p.sampled_issue_date = dateToRender
    return p
  }

  // generic georeducer
  function geoReducerDefault() {
    return {
      count: 0,
      sampled_mail_subscriptions: 0,
      sampled_single_copy_sales: 0,
      sampled_total_sales: 0,
      state_population: 0,
      sampled_issue_date: ""
    }
  }
```

The problem could be somewhere else, but I don't think it's a crossfilter issue (I'm not running into the "two groups from the same dimension" problem for sure) and adding additional logic to the add reducer makes things even less predictable (understandably - I don't ever really need to render the sample date for all values anyway.) The point of this is that I'm completely lost about where the flaw in my logic is, and I'd love some help!

EDIT: Note that the reducers are for the `reduce` method on a dc.js dimension, not the native javascript reducer! :D

Comment: This may not be the root cause of your problem, but one thing that looks immediately suspicious is that your reducers are mutating state. Reducers should generally be pure functions without side effects. You should only make  copies of state within your reducers.

Comment: Ah, yeah - so get this, I had to do that because before, when I just did `p.sampled_issue_date = v.sampled_issue_date`, then I would get the correct date... It was just always off by one. So if I clicked an issue from 1921, it would show 1968 as the date, and then the second click on an issue from 1945 would show the correct sample date from 1921. Next click would show the date from 1945, and so on. Truly bizarre (and note that this isn't a problem for other categorical data like `editor` in my circulation data!)

Comment: Your reduce is `reduce(geoReducerAdd, geoReducerRemove, geoReducerDefault)`, first param in `reduce` is callback and second is `initialValue`, but you have `callback function geoReducerRemove` as a second parameter.

Comment: @randomSoul good instinct, but this is a method on a dc.js dimension, not the native reduce method on javascript arrays. You can [learn more about it at this link](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#reducing-rows-that-each-contain-multiple-values)

Comment: I'm not able to repro in your demo. I reload the page and then click on an issue. The date shows in the lower chart and the choropleth fades to what looks like the same values as clicking nearby dates. Have you fixed this already? Sounds like it's just a UI bug and not really dc.js/crossfilter related but I'm not sure. Really neat viz btw!

Comment: Actually, what I see is that as soon as you hover, it fades to that date range. Then if you click, it stays there, and hovering no longer changes anything, only clicking will change the filter.

Comment: @Gordon You should see it when you hover over a state (like Idaho, not a hover state) in the choropleth. The `Sample Issue Date (for Geodata)` field will be for a date in 1968, but it should be April 30, 1921. It's correct if you keep clicking around though.

Also, thanks for the compliment (and for all of your stackoverflow help up to this point, haha)

Comment: What is the intention of checking `state.periodStart` and `state.periodEnding` inside the reduce-remove function? I would think you wouldn't want to set `sampled_issue_date` or `state_population` in the remove function at all, since they are just supposed to replicate values that will be the same across all rows in that fall into that bin.

Comment: btw, the irrelevant advice is due to using the [javascript] tag. it's best to leave off that tag when asking crossfilter questions because at best people won't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two crossfilters! Always fun to see that... but it can be tricky because nothing in dc.js directly supports that, except for the chart registry. You're on your own for filtering between different chart groups, and it can be tricky to map between data sets with different time resolutions and so on.

#### The problem

As I understand your app, when a date is selected in the line chart, the choropleth and accompanying text should have exactly one row from the geodata dataset selected per state.

The essential problem is that Crossfilter is not great at telling you which rows are in any given bin. So even though there's just one row selected, you don't know what it is!

This is the same problem that makes [minimum, maximum, and median reductions](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/complex-reduce.html) surprisingly complicated. You often end up building new data structures to capture what crossfilter throws away in the name of efficiency.

#### A general solution

I'll go with a general solution that's more that you need, but can be helpful in similar situations. The only alternative that I know is to go completely outside crossfilter and look in the original dataset. That's fine too, and maybe more efficient. But it can be buggy and it's nice to work within the system.

So let's keep track of which dates we've seen per bin. When we start out, every bin will have all the dates. Once a date is selected, there will be only one date (but not exactly the one that was selected, because of your two-crossfilter setup).

Instead of the `sampled_issue_date` stuff, we'll keep track of an object called `date_counts` now:

```
  // Reducer function for raw geodata
  function geoReducerAdd(p, v) {
    // ...
    const canonDate = new Date(v.sampled_issue_date).getTime()
    p.date_counts[canonDate] = (p.date_counts[canonDate] || 0) + 1
    return p
  }
  function geoReducerRemove(p, v) {
    // ...
    const canonDate = new Date(v.sampled_issue_date).getTime()
    if(!--p.date_counts[canonDate])
      delete p.date_counts[canonDate]
    return p
  }
  // generic georeducer
  function geoReducerDefault() {
    return {
    // ...
      date_counts: {}
    }
  }
```

What does it do?

#### Line by line

```
    const canonDate = new Date(v.sampled_issue_date).getTime()
```

Maybe this is paranoid, but this canonicalizes the input dates by converting them to the number of milliseconds since 1970. I'm sure you'd be safe using the string dates directly, but who knows there could be a space or a zero or something.

You can't index an object with a date object, you have to convert it to an integer.

```
    p.date_counts[canonDate] = (p.date_counts[canonDate] || 0) + 1
```

When we add a row, we'll check if we currently have a count for the row's date. If so, we'll use the count we have. Otherwise we'll default to zero. Then we'll add one.

```
    if(!--p.date_counts[canonDate])
      delete p.date_counts[canonDate]
```

When we remove a row, we know that we have a count for the date for that row (because crossfilter won't tell us it's removing the row unless it was added earlier). So we can go ahead and decrement the count. Then if it hits zero we can remove the entry.

Like I said, it's overkill. In your case, the count will only go to 1 and then drop to 0. But it's not much more expensive to this rather than just keep

#### Rendering the side panel

When we render the side panel, there should only be one date left in `date_counts` for that selected item.

```
console.assert(Object.keys(date_counts).length === 1) // only one entry
console.assert(Object.entries(date_counts)[0][1] === 1) // with count 1
document.getElementById('geo-issue-date').textContent = new Date(+Object.keys(date_counts)[0]).format('mmm dd, yyyy')
```

#### Usability notes

From a usability perspective, I would recommend not to `filter(null)` on mouseleave, or if you really want to, then put it on a timeout which gets cancelled when you see a mouseenter. One should be able to "scrub" over the line chart and see the changes over time in the choropleth without accidentally switching back to the unfiltered colors.

I also noticed ([and filed](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/1528)) an issue because I noticed that dots to the right of the mouse pointer are shown, making them difficult to click. The reason is that the dots are overlapping, so only a little sliver of a crescent is hoverable. At least with my trackpad, the click causes the pointer to travel leftward. (I can see the date go back a week in the tooltip and then return.) It's not as much of a problem when you're zoomed in.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you so much for providing such a detailed answer. I finally got around to implementing it today, and it works! I also appreciate the broader feedback on the visualization - to your point, it's been surprisingly tricky. Regarding the mouseleave: I agree that it's a little messy, but my concern is that I want the choropleth to reset when they leave the line chart. I'll fiddle with it, I agree that there could be performance issues, and maybe I'm missing the mouseleave animation in the choropleth